# No data returned in a aws-sdk Promise

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, es6-promise

I'm calling DynamoDB's PutItem as my first es6 promises attempt on AWS Lambda with Node 4.3.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var req = d.putItem(params={
  'TableName': TABLE,
  ...
}).promise();
req.then(function(resp) {
  console.log("sresp", resp);
  // I want to do more with the returned data here
});
```

And here's what shows up in the console:

```
sresp {}
```

There are a few questions about Promises in the AWS SDK (javascript) that are from the "pre-promises" era; as of March 2016 there's native support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB `putItem` request doesn't return anything by default. You have to specify a value for one or more of the following parameters in order to get something back (they all default to `NONE`):

```
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'INDEXES | TOTAL | NONE',
  ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'SIZE | NONE',
  ReturnValues: 'NONE | ALL_OLD | UPDATED_OLD | ALL_NEW | UPDATED_NEW'
```

Comment: aha- in the pre-promises world I'd check that the http response was correct, looks like that isn't necessary as the `error` and `catch` should work. Note "PutItem does not recognize any values other than NONE or ALL_OLD.".